# php for this week and next

Tags: php, date

I can get the date of the Monday for the current week, but how do I get it to display "and (the date for the monday of next week)"?

For example, "March 6 and 13, 2017"

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php echo date('F j, Y',strtotime(date('o-\WW')));?>
```

Comment: Can you make strtotime() work?  "echo strtotime('Next Monday, 9:00:00 am');"?

Comment: "<?php echo strtotime('Next Monday');?>" displays "1488758400"

Comment: Yes, a unix timestamp, for which you would use date() to format it according to your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the far more readable:

```
echo date('F j, Y',strtotime('Monday this week'));
echo date('F j, Y',strtotime('Monday next week'));
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I ended up with this:  For the Week of <?php echo date('F j',strtotime('Monday this week'));?> and <?php echo date('F j, Y',strtotime('Monday next week'));?>

Comment: @modernmagic If you feel that this answer helped you, please considering marking it as accepted. I see you've asked nine questions but haven't accepted an answer for any of them. Accepting an answer lets everyone know the answer helped you and also increases rep for you and the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

An *exact* script:

```
$this_monday = date("F j", strtotime("Monday this week"));
$next_monday = date("j, Y", strtotime("Monday next week"));

echo $this_monday . " and " . $next_monday;
```

The problem will be crossing months.  If you need to do that, you'll need more logic, perhaps something like:

```
$this_monday = strtotime("Monday this week");
$next_monday = strtotime("Monday next week");

if (date("F",$this_monday) === date("F",$next_monday)) {

    echo date("F j", $this_monday) . " and " . date("j, Y", $next_monday);

} else {

    echo date("F j", $this_monday) . " and " . date("F j, Y", $next_monday);
}
```

Someone may come along and suggest using the Datetime class instead, and that might be something to put on your list to learn, as well.